# Wait until ajax done before returning the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use this code to get a message from the server and print it to the frontend:

```
var message = getMessageFromServer();
$('.result').html(message);

function getMessageFromServer() {
    var result = null;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (msg) {
            result = msg;
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

It obviously isn't working because as how javascript works, the line `return result` is running before the ajax done, therefore my function `getMessageFromServer` always return null.

I have searched all day about this problem and got many answers such as setting async to false, using when done, callback, re-structuring the code to be more ajax-friendly, etc. However, I'm using a framework that won't let me freely re-structuring my code, so I need to make the question myself: **How do I print the message to the frontend with below conditions**:

- The 2 first lines must not be changed, I need to return the result to `message`, so it can be print to the frontend.
- Not using the `async: false` because it's bad for user experience.
- We can create more method, as long as it is used within the function `getMessageFromServer`

P/s: If you're wondering, the framework I'm using is Magento and I'm trying to add a custom validation rule with AJAX, but I the main problem is javascript so I didn't put it into the tags.

Comment: Can't you just move the return statement inside the "success" callback?

Comment: @GrafiCode that won't work.

Comment: @Pointy why not?

Comment: @GrafiCode because it is asynchronous....

Comment: It doesn't matter. If you move `return` inside the `success`, you will just get "undefined" instead of "null", because javascript will run the function to the end without waiting for the AJAX to be done.

Comment: Ok I see it now, it works setting the HTML directly instead of returning it, thanks for the explaination

Comment: *"The 2 first lines must not be changed"* - then you're stuffed as that's simply not how *asynchronous* works.

Answer (score 0):

It's the nature of JS and asynchronous callbacks.
Instead of assigning the `var message = getMessageFromServer()`, you should instead set the `$('.result')` from within the success callback.

```
getMessageFromServer();

function getMessageFromServer() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (msg) {
            $('.result').html(msg);
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: As I state in the question, the first two line must not be changed, and the message must be returned from `getMessageFromServer`. All because of the framework I'm working on.

Comment: @Mee it's simply not possible to do that.

Comment: It is possible using  promise object @Pointy

Comment: @Rishab read the question: "the first 2 lines must not be changed". Those lines of code do not anticipate receiving a Promise object, so the question is impossible as posed.

Comment: Let him try this https://jsfiddle.net/Luo2n6dh/

Comment: @Rishab the jsfiddle is completely blank, could you check it again?

Comment: @Mee well, what I suggested does work, https://glitch.com/edit/#!/economic-expansion